# Implementing Group-Based Permission Management for an existing C# MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing web application that is already using Identity 2.0 and the basic login functionality that comes with creating a new MVC 5 web app on the Azure cloud with the "Individual Accounts" setting set (the MVC app was created with VS 2013 update 4).

I want to add more data to my user model such as role (Guest, Member, Moderator, Admin) so that they have different experiences and options available to them on the web application.

I have been working on this problem for a few weeks and the only success I have found is with the following:

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/08/10/ASPNET-Identity-20-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management.aspx

The problem I am having with these tutorials is that they require you to create a brand new project and use the Identity 2.0 sample project which adds a significant amount of views and controllers that make the project very hard to understand what is going on:

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

Is this really the best tutorials out there for implementing this functionality? I feel like the addition of two controllers, X number of views, and the repetition that comes with just adding a simple thing such as an address (as demonstrated in the first link) shouldn't be an undertaking where I am writing near identical code in over 5-8 places.

Are there any other good tutorials that are recommended for me to do that will show me how to add roles to each user, and then be able to tailor the experience of the website by role?

Thank you for any help in this matter.

Comment: The examples you;ve provided dont require you re-add or install the nuget packages if you already have them in use. Just start further down past those steps. You need to add near identical code in 3-4 places because you need to update the model, view and the controller if you want to use any of the new properties you are adding. If you just want to differentiate your view based on roles then simply use a switch statement in you action methods on your controller to determine role and return appropriate view thos that would soon get ugly so maybe use a custom helper to generate role based links